# Tableau: Get the ids that contain only the selected values from another column

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have the following question!
I have a table like this:

[Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EpwN.png)

I want to create a field(i suppose it's a field) that i can take the apl_ids,
that have as service_offered some that i want.

Example from the above table. If i want the apl_ids that have ONLY the service_offered
Pending 1, Pending 2 and Pending 7.

In that case, I want to get the apl_id  = "13" since apl_id = "12" got one more service that i don't need.

Which is the best way to get that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You uploaded the wrong screenshot.

Comment: You are right sir, I just uploaded the right one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a calculated field which gives 1 for desired values and 0 for other values.  Add another calc field with fixed LOD to apl_id to sum of calcF1. Filter all ids with values=3 only.  I think that should work.
Else tell me I will post screenshots

Comment: One more thing Sir! Is it possible in the same Sheet, to get the COUNTD of apl_ids ignoring the filter(for comparison)? Once again thank you!

Comment: Yes, Simply duplicate the view, i.e. apl_ids in rows, calc_F2 in filters.  This time set the filter at most 2. This will filter all other apl_ids.  Next put countD of services in text marks

Comment: Or simply if you want other apl_ids countD only, create a third calc_field as `SUM({Fixed [apl_id]: sum( If [calcF2]<=2 then 1 else 0 END)})` and put it in view

Comment: Please accept the snswer snd upvote it if served the purpose, as usually desired on SO

Comment: Just did sir! If you think my question can help others, please upvote it as well! Thanks

Comment: I already had! Thanks.  Can you please tell me how many different pending statuses you have.  If total number is less than 12-15 i can present an alternative and better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a set based on the field api_id defined by the condition

```
max([service_offering]=“Pending 1”) and
max([service_offering]=“Pending 2”) and
max([service_offering]=“Pending 7”) and
min([service_offering]=“Pending 1” or [service_offering]=“Pending 2” or [service_offering]=“Pending 7”)
```

This set will contain those api_ids that have at least one record where service_offering is “Pending 1” and at least one record with Pending 2 ... and where every record has a service offering of 1, 2 or 7 (I.e. no others)

The key is to realize that Tableau treats True as greater than False, so min() and max() for boolean expressions correspond to every() and any().

Once you have a set of api_ids() you can use it on shelves and in calculated fields in many different ways.

Comment: That's really helpuf Sir! I will try it and let you know!